# HTML 5 Autofocus messes up CSS loading

Tags: css, html, firefox, autofocus

When I set `autofocus="autofocus"` on an input element, then in Firefox, when the page loads, it displays for a split second without the CSS applied. (E.g. content not centered, heading rendered in default font etc.)

If I remove the autofocus, the page loads fine and displays when it is ready.

Is there a way to get the page to load normally while using the `autofocus` feature in Firefox?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712130

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found that by adding some JavaScript in the `<head>`, the page waits for the style to load before the focus.

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but it does!

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Fix for Firefox autofocus CSS bug
    // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943276/html-5-autofocus-messes-up-css-loading/18945951#18945951
</script>
```

Comment: This works because it blocks the browser and it seems that this short blocking is enough for Firefox to correctly lay out the page in the background.

Comment: It seems this bug has been fixed very recently and will land in FF 60: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712130

Comment: I'm seeing this in Firefox 89.