# Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) in Firefox only? Is FF slow renderer?

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet, font-face, fouc

I'm not seeing this issue in any other browser that I've tested - IE, Chrome, Opera - but whenever I load a page from the server, I'm seeing a flash of unstyled content before the CSS is applied.

This is even happening on subsequent page loads where everything should be cached - every time the page loads I see the unstyled content for a split-second, then everything settles in.

It's also worth noting (perhaps?) that the page is using @font-face to pull some Google fonts. They are stored in a separate stylesheet being pulled after the main responsive stylesheets and media queries.

I've tried a few different things, to no effect:

- Rearranging order of CSS stylesheet links
- Removing link to stylesheets with @font-face
- Disabling Firebug? (Read on here somewhere...)

One other thing that may be worth mentioning is that I used quite a lot of Element Type CSS selectors in the page's CSS. Is it possible that this is slowing down the rendering process?

This seems unlikely as there is no problem immediately re-rendering the page upon changing the dimensions of the window - the responsive stuff renders fine immediately.

So this leads me to believe that there is some issue with how the CSS is being loaded.

Here is my HEAD code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!--<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<title></title>

<!-- responsive stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/320.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:320px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/480.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/768.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/960.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:960px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/960+.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:961px)" />

<!-- custom fonts stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/ui/favicon.ico">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/960+.css" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

WTF is going wrong with Firefox? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: The bit you pasted shouldn't cause any flashes of unstyled content (though it _could_ in theory cause flashes of content not yet using the downloadable font... but only if that takes a while to load).  Just to check, do you see the behavior in safe mode?  See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode#w_how-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Thanks for the feedback, I'll try loading the fonts onto the server instead of pulling them from Google for now. Not sure about safe mode, will look into that.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943276/html-5-autofocus-messes-up-css-loading/18945951#18945951

Comment: @BorisZbarsky i followed the whole content in the link to mozila firefox help center. but it did not change my problem. I am facing this issue only in beisat.org and no other places.

Answer (score 53):

If you add a dummy `<script>` tag right after `<body>`, Firefox will show the page after all the css from `<head>` is loaded:

```html
<body>
   <script>0</script>
   <!-- rest of the code -->
</body>
```

There is an official bugreport about this FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) on the Firefox site: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468

Comment: Seems to fix it for those with the inspector open with the console warning: "Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content."

Comment: did not work for me - perhaps because it's a reintroduced bug? It is 2022, after all :-/

Comment: 2023, bug's still here but the dummy script fixed it for me. I wonder if there's an actual way to approach this without using the dummy script. But I guess for now I'll have to use it.

Comment: It happens for me even with <script>0</script> in the body.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem with `Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.` showing in the console, and a **visible flash of unstyled content** upon page refresh, withouth (F5) or with clearing the cache (Ctrl + F5). Having the **developer tools** open does not made a difference either.

What helped me was **declaring a variable in a script** just before the `</head>` tag ended, so basically after all the `<link>` tags.

It's important to note, that an empty script (or with just a comment) or any random javaScript would not help, but declaring a variable worked.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/other.css" />

  <script>
    /*to prevent Firefox FOUC, this must be here*/
    let FF_FOUC_FIX;
  </script>
</head>
```

There was no need to rearrange links or not use imports within css or js files.

**Please note that the issue will no longer be visible (FOUC is visibly gone), but the console might still show the same warning.**

Comment: Solved the issue for me.. Even the warning is no longer showing up.

Answer (score 15):

I was experiencing this error. A colleague has said that it's caused by the attribute, `autofocus` being added to a form field.

By removing this attribute and using JavaScript to set the focus the brief flash of unstyled content stops happening.

Comment: I experienced the same problem in Firefox 57.0.1 and can confirm that removing `autofocus` solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the flash is caused by `autofocus`, then it can be solved without removing autofocus by adding an empty `<script>` tag to the head, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147149/flash-of-unstyled-content-fouc-in-firefox-only-is-ff-slow-renderer

Comment: It seems this bug will be fixed in FF 60: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712130

Comment: YES YES YES!! Thank you! How in the world can all of this be happening because of one little input text field with autofocus. I don't know how your friend discovered this being autofocus related, but wow. Thank you!

Comment: I can see this error message also on pages that do not have any input field at all. :E

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, I had this same problem and found that it was being caused by having poorly formatted `<html>...</html>` tags.

To be precise, in my code I accidentally closed the HTML tag too early, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
  <title>My title</title>
```

The code provided by the original poster is missing the opening `<html>` so I suspect that's probably what is happening there.

Answer (score 6):

Filament Group share they way they load their fonts in detail,

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html

which is a nice modern approach to @font-face loading

Smashing magazine also review there website performance and came up with a different solution that stores the caches a base64 copy of the font in local storage. This solution may require a different licence for you font.

A gist can be found at:

https://gist.github.com/hdragomir/8f00ce2581795fd7b1b7

The original article detailing their decision can be fount at:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/08/improving-smashing-magazine-performance-case-study/#webfonts

### Additional recommendation

The head of your document contains far to many individual stylesheets, all these css files should be combined into a single file, minified and gziped. You may have a second link for your fonts placed before you main stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue. In my case removing `@import` rule in the CSS file and linking all the CSS files in the HTML resolved it.

Comment: This was my problem, I never would have thought of moving that to the html...

Comment: I thought it helped, but after the second refresh the message appeared again..

Answer (score 5):

In my case the reason of FOUC in FF was the presence of iframe on page.
If I removing iframe from markup then FOUC disappears.

But I need iframe for my own hacking reasons so I changed this

```
<iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="display: none;position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

into this

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let nBody = document.querySelector('body')
    let nIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    nIframe.setAttribute('name', "hidden-iframe");
    nIframe.style.display = 'none';
    nIframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    nBody.appendChild(nIframe);
  });
</script>
```

I've added this inline JS right in template just for readability: in my case this code runs once per page.
I know that it's dirty hack, so you can add this code in separated JS-file.

The problem was in Firefox Quantum v65.

Comment: Still getting this in 2024 lol I remove the iframes no problem, I put them back in and hit happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (but also in chrome). Even if many of the existing answers provide clues to the reason for FOUC I wanted to present my problem and its solution.

As I said, I had FOUC in a fairly large project and already had the suspicion of a racecondition in some form.

In the project SASS is used and via a "bootstrap" file for the css a fontawesome free package was added via import.

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

This import has increased the total size of the css file by a lot, which caused the file to take a long time to load, and the browser went and already loaded the following javascript.
The JS that was then executed forced the rendering of its content and thus created the FOUC.

So the solution in my case was to remove the big fontawesome package and insert the icons I used from it (~10) via an [Icomoon custom font](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select). Not only did this solve the FOUC but it also had the nice side effect that the delivered CSS files are much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (AWS Amplify), I was using a 302 redirect from https://website.com to https://www.website.com. Switching to a 301 redirect fixed this.

The problem could be a cache mixup for the background image on my site, since the bottleneck was some hundred ms of latency to download it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, there is a full working and easy solution.

- In FF `devtools`, disable `warnings`, and..: DONE.

Maybe my answer look somehow funny, but i explain myself.

This warning is there for a reason and it has to do with rendering of a `html` page.

Since `html5` i never: 1) use `head` tag, 2) use `body` tag, 3) never close the `html` tag. I don't say this is the right way, but is what i do and what i will continue to do. No matter this, in `devtools` `inspector`, FF have separate my `code` and add both `HEAD` and `BODY` tags. So FF pasre -> categorize the source -> organize and try to optimize the loading of a page.

In short when FF sees an not `link`,`script`,`meta` tag, starts the `BODY` parsing. if later you have some css code that may alter the view of that `BODY` above, then that, maybe flush your view... Didn't you know that ? Of course you already know this! That's what the warning say

So, if want not to see the warning, design your code more `right` and think like a browser. Also remember that

- `javasrcipt` and rendering is a mostly synchronous process.
- even if `write` code thinking as above, fetching resourses may also cause the warning to show.

So, am i the clever one that design everything right and not see this ? Of course not. Otherwise never search and land here.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by importing my CSS file in my JS file. Solved this by linking my CSS file in the HTML.

This makes the browser wait for the CSS to load before rendering content, which doesn't happen when CSS is dynamically loaded from a JS import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).