# Autofocus doesn't work on Firefox and doesn't work when coming from another page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, autofocus

I'm creating my page using Javascript. It is a login page and I need to use autofocus on username input text. This operation works on IE and Chrome, but doesn't on Mozilla!
This is the HTML I have been adding using JS:

```
'<input id="username" class="loginInput" data-bind="value: userName, valueUpdate: \'afterkeydown\'" type="text" name="User" autofocus><!--User Input text end /-->'
```

When i load the page with Mozilla this input is set this way:

```
<input id="username" class="loginInput" type="text" autofocus="" name="User" data-bind="value: userName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

I really can't understand why `autofocus` attribute is set in that way. I even tried by adding the attribute using JQuery `$("#username").attr('autofocus','autofocus')` and works only on Chrome and IE.

The second problem comes when I go to the login page from another page and `autofocus` issue comes with every browser.

Can you help me?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943276/html-5-autofocus-messes-up-css-loading/18945951#18945951

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$("#username").focus();
```

after the page has been loaded.

Comment: still forced to do that in 2019, only for firefox, thank you even if it's hacky

Comment: 2022 and still the case in FF 106 Linux. :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `autofocus` attribute, try:

```
$("#username").focus();
```